# Is there a JavaFX class hierarchy graph?

Tags: java, javafx

Is there any available plot/graph/pdf/etc of the JavaFX class and interface hierarchy, showing the properties and methods added at each level?

The only thing I found was this which is pretty good, 
[image]
[image]

But I was hoping for the full hierarchy of all classes available in JFX.  I would expect a very large PDF...something like what's been seen for [wxWidgets](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/wxWidgets/wxposter.png)

Presumably this is automatable by someone more skilled than me, and presumably it's been done already... maybe in Doxygen or something?  If someone has a link I would be very grateful.  I'm looking specifically how all the various properties and ObservableValues tie in to each other.

thank you

Comment: Try the official [JavaFX Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/overview-summary.html). Though it doesn't show the relation, it has everything you need. :)

Comment: What @ItachiUchiha said but click on [Tree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/overview-tree.html)

Comment: I've stared at the docs and it's too much text.  I was hoping for more graphical boxes that show the functions and properties, showing heirarchy graphically rather than text.  No problem, I'm taking a break from JFX for a while.